# Predicting the future?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, story, situation

I was browsing my email one morning when I got this curious email:

> Date: February 17, 2020
>
> Subject: Want to see the future?
>
> Hello, I am a clairvoyant who can predict the future. I have made a fortune from my talent and now I want to share it to you. However, this knowledge is not free. For just $129.99 you can enroll into my clairvoyant class
>
> Don't believe me? Here's a vision of the future free of charge: This week, the stock market will go down, so please withdraw all your money.

Without hesitation, I deleted the email, thinking it was spam that somehow made it through the spam filter. Later this week, the stock market did indeed [plunge rapidly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_stock_market_crash).

The following week I received another email:

> Date: February 28, 2020
>
> Subject: Want to see the future?
>
> Do you believe me now? If you are, just know that for just $129.99 you can enroll into my clairvoyant class.
>
> Still don't believe me? Here's another vision of the future free of charge: This upcoming Saturday, in a major upset, Watford will defeat Liverpool and end their winning streak.

"What a scam!" I thought. It was easy to predict a stock market crash, considering a pandemic coming. But to predict that Liverpool, the most dominating team in the football league, will lose to a team standing at the bottom of the table? The next day, to my dismay, [Watford did beat Liverpool](https://www.liverpoolfc.com/news/first-team/388739-match-report-liverpool-watford-premier-league) in a major upset.

Next week, I received another email:

> Date: March 2, 2020
>
> Subject: Want to see the future?
>
> Do you believe me now? If you are, just know that for just $129.99 you can enroll into my clairvoyant class! Too expensive? Remember that this class will help you see the future for the rest of your life!
>
> Still don't believe me? Here's my last free vision of the future: You play the lottery? The Powerball for this Wednesday will be 14.

Sure enough, the Powerball number is [14 on Wednesday](https://www.txlottery.org/export/sites/lottery/Games/Powerball/Winning_Numbers/details.html_1152832806.html).

I am absolutely perplexed. On one hand, I still believe that this is a very elaborate scam. On the other hand, I still have zero idea how can he predict the stock market, sporting event, and even lottery number with absolute accuracy.

How does he do it?

Comment: Well of course they are actually clairvoyant... /s

Comment: If I was the scammer I would not make the prediction that Watford will beat Liverpool, because it is so unlikely...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It is is a scam that it depends on probabilities and outcomes: At first, they are making 2 target groups. For the first target group they send an email in which they claim that the market is going to rise and for the second target group they send an email in which they claim that the markets will go down. According to the outcome, next week they send an email only to those that their "prediction" was right. They are making new target groups and so on until someone believes them. In fact, 260 emails are needed at least in order that at least 1 person will receive 3 "successful predictions": https://i.stack.imgur.com/2leQ5.jpg

Comment: rot13("bayl gb gubfr gung gurve 'cerqvpgvba' jnf evtug": cyhf gubfr jub qvqa'g [bcra gur r-znvy](//google.com/search?q=email+open_tracking+pixel))

Comment: @msh210 You may have deleted your answer but I think your point about sending **a large volume** of emails is crucial to the situation. In practice only a very small percentage will believe it is genuine. When carried out in real life the sender sends *loads* of these things out to try and snag the one person who will invest. Stratos, I think you should mention the volume of emails to round your answer out nicely :)

Comment: The question is "How does he do it?". It's not about how to succeed in this kind of business, so I don't think that the volume of emails is relevant to the question.

Comment: That's fine, it's your choice. Often I find fleshing out an answer with more context and colour to give a fully rounded solution is helpful - but it's your answer, not mine...

Comment: Nice touch, well illustrated :)

Comment: Thanks @Stiv, considering your advice I thought that the minimum number of the needed emails would be a nice "extra" touch.

Comment: Isn't there the possibility that rot13(the market stays more or less the same)

Comment: So? What possible piece of advice could you give to another person in order to earn from it? I thought about that and that's why I didn't include this possibility to my answer @Mohirl

Comment: @Mohirl you might want to change that rot13 there lol

Comment: Ha! I'm always doing that but I usually catch it before I post it  @Stratos Fair point

Comment: I just disagree regarding the Liverpool match. All the other events are close to equally probable. The Liverpool losing was not equally probable to the other alternatives. So, if I were the scammer, I would choose n events with the same 1/n probability of happening and distribute my emails homogeneously. At this step, the scammer will probably choose events with a relatively low probability of happening in order to impress the victim.